# How do I resolve an error regarding launching a React application through my terminal using the command `npm run start`?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I've been trying to launch a React application (localhost:3000) by typing `npm run start` on Windows Powershell (I'm using Windows 11), but I'm getting the following error.

```
> dojo-blog@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.196.11.178/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\udayp\OneDrive\Documents\React_Tutorial\dojo-blog\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.9.0
```

I have nvm, npm and Node.js installed, and I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling them too, and yet, nothing seems to be working. I have been using ChatGPT-3.5 as a co-pilot while dealing with installation- and terminal- related errors, and I have followed some of its suggestions too, such as running `npm cache clean --force`, `nvm install LTS_VERSION` and `npm install` several times until the required installations and library updates were complete.

There were many other steps too which I tried following, but this error continues to prevent me from being able to open the application. I'm quite new to React, JS, and terminal commands in general, so any suggestions on how to get around this problem would be most welcome :)